# FB.ui ea.result is null

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, fb.ui

When I make an apprequests (share or invite), the popin is shown correctly, but if I click on the cancel button, this message appear in the Firebug console : TypeError: ea.result is null

Is it a Facebook bug ?

Answer (score 0):

[It's submitted to their bug tracker](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/364928233616843?browse=search_516e7aea2ffdf9128852578)

Comment: You mean http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/181204965365119?browse=search_516e90ff568550461093639

Comment: Quite the same. [And another one.](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/518441864864394)